# What are lb-140-82-[XXX]-[XXX]-[a-z]*.github.com links?

Tags: github

While scanning some program network activity, I've found that it sends a request to `lb-140-82-121-3-fra.github.com`. After a quick [search](https://superuser.com/search?q=lb-140-82) I've found out that there are more similar links. The IPs in the links belong to github IP-range, so both `lb-140-82-121-3-fra.github.com` and `140.82.121.3` will redirect me to github.com. What's the purpose of these links?

Comment: It’s important to use correct terminology. Those are not links, also not URLs. They are host names. They appear to you because of reverse DNS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Github dosen't run on 'one' server - it runs on many servers, including potentially CDNs, load balancers and 'actual' web servers and databases. There's probably a complicated system of things that determines what server(s) you actually connect to, usually hidden away unless you're actually looking at connections that were made

It is likely "lb" refers to load balancer, I'd guess they include the IP in the domain name for easy trouble shooting, and the "fra" or "ams"  refers to the geographical location its in - either in a cloud instance or a physical datacenter.

Its a very neat setup if someone reports an issue, or better yet automated systems pick up and report an issue, and all the information you need to identify the role, IP and location of a server to troubleshoot an issue.

Comment: "fra" looks like France, but what's "ams"? American South? Amsterdam?

Comment: @wjandrea It's almost certainly Frankfurt (am Main, Germany) and Amsterdam, both major internet hubs.